# Remove but 'remember' (to later restore) duplicate frames from video/ image sequence?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, deduplication

I'm upscaling animated content (via ChaiNNer) in which a number of frames (often 25-50%) are duplicates, wasting significant gpu time; I've been attempting to remove duplicates pre upscale but have the video play as if they were still there when the upscaled frames a re-encoded.

I've attempted to use FFMPEG's mpdecimate filter but it seems to restore the duplicate frames when the video is extracted to png's (to allow upscaling)

Essentially I'd like to remove the duplicates pre-upscale and restore them (albeit based off the upscaled rather than original frames) after the upscale is complete/ when encoding the final video; alternatively if I can take the frame timings information from the mpdecimated video and apply it to the final encode of the upscale I believe it would serve the same purpose.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to do something twice in order to do a faster first pass. You're going to have to use the GPU time anyway to upscale the frames you removed earlier on, aren't you? Or it'll be more GPU time to make guesses and reconstruct the removed information. I seems to me the fastest OVERALL method is simply to upscale everything at once, in one pass. If your workflow requires a faster rush pass initially, you'll just have to plan to do a slower full pass later to create the final product. Note, this is based on a very limited understanding of FFMPEG.

Comment: @music2myear The idea is to remove frames that are identical to previous/ following and then restore then using the upscaled versions of the previous/ following, so the removed frames never actually need to be upscaled.

E.g. frame 2 is indentical to frame one, frame 1 is upscaled and frame 2 is discarded but frame 1 is then copied to create a new frame 2 upscaling only once